# How to log when a directory is no longer being written to

Tags: linux, rhel, logs, disk

Without going into too many details, we have a situation where files are being written constantly to a drive on a RHEL 6 server. What we need to do is to log when a certain directory hasn't been written to in a certain period of time, say 24 hours, and have the system generate an alert - is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

You could check the modification timestamps of the files in that directory, looking for files modified less than 24 hours ago. If you find none, then generate an alert.

```
#!/bin/sh
MONITOR_DIR=/some/directory
NUM_NEW_FILES=$(find "$MONITOR_DIR" -mtime -1 | wc -l)
if [ $NUM_NEW_FILES -eq 0 ]
then
    # change this to generate an alert of preferred type
    echo "All files in $MONITOR_DIR are at least 24h old!" 
fi
```